# jQuery attr not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working with asp.net, C#, jQuery 1.8.3/1.7.2

I want to change a textbox "Readonly" attribute to 'true' or 'false' in script when the page loads.
***updated***The value to the textbox loads at runtime..
Here is the script:

```
function hidebtn() {        
    $('#diviv').css({
        "display": "block"
    });

    $("#txtname").attr('ReadOnly', true);
}
```

If I write a alert, it working fine, now div appears well. The txtname attribute is not changing. I am calling this method from codebehind like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "hidebtn();", true);
```

Comment: Does the `#txtname` element exist?

Comment: $('#test').attr('readonly', 'readonly'); Try this

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Yeah it exists in a table on the same page. :-(

Comment: @krshekhar: Ok ..with javascript same issue, alert, style works only readonly doesnt turn up..

Comment: @ShivaKomuravelly: Tried dude..no result.. $(#test).attr('readonly',false); isnt working too..not in any browser !

Comment: set controls property `ReadOnly` to `False`

Comment: @krshekhar And if the control is not runat=server ?

Comment: I'm not saying it is correct to lowercase, but it does **not** seem to matter : http://jsbin.com/uhubiq/3/edit/

Comment: @RoyiNamir ` <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly>`

Comment: @PranavKapoor **readonly doesnt have to have any value** !. it just a markup attribute. you can only add "readonly" to the html element and it will be "readonly"

Comment: @krshekhar I thought you mean _set controls property ReadOnly_ by runat server approach.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I didnt set true/false in aspx. and i added runat="server". any problem with that ?

Comment: @codebrain if the control is runat server , so why do you need js in order to set it to readonly ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir : I'm saying `readonly === ReadOnly` (Attributes are case in-sensitive), no?

Comment: @PranavKapoor yeah but in your example only the value was case-insensitive.....well never mind we both get the picture.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The text is loaded at runtime. Its user profile information. If 'edit'(linkbutton) is clicked i want to set readonly=false in script, and by default i want to set readonly=true..thats how my TL wants..

Comment: @codebrain please try setting readonly this way : "instead of making the textbox readonly using properties option.....

write the code....TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");"

Comment: @RoyiNamir : Yup, I was changing it via jQuery. I specifically said this, since most answers below pointed out that it was because of it not being lowercase (at least before edits :P). Anyway nevermind.

Comment: :-P yeah ..Im trying all the suggestions. BTW im using chrome ?!? im trying with firefox and will let u friends know soon :-) Thanks @RoyiNamir : Thanks :-) ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [**ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) the script block should execute after the page is finished loading but before the page's `OnLoad` event is fired.

If you happen to add your textbox in your `OnLoad` event then the selector will never see find the control.

Either way you should check if your control exists at the time the script is run.
You could do this by executing:

```
console.log($("#txtname").length); //or
alert($("#txtname").length);
```

If the length is not `0` then something else might be overwriting your `readonly` setting. Maybe the control is re-rendered after the script has been run or similar.

If the length is `0` then your control is not yet on the page.

You could try wrapping the code in a `$(document).ready(function(){//yourcode here})` to see if it makes a difference.

You can use a stringbuilder instead then to build the script and use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` instead similar to this:

```
StringBuilder hideBtnScript = new StringBuilder();

hideBtnScript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
hideBtnScript.Append("$(document).ready(function() {");
hideBtnScript.Append("$('#diviv').css({'display': 'block'});");
hideBtnScript.Append("$('#txtname').prop('readonly', true);});");
hideBtnScript.Append("</script>");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Call my function", hideBtnScript.ToString(), false);
```

Comment: The textbox is rendered through server side ( i believe) and the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is adding the script at the bottom of the page is he must recognize the textbox.

Comment: and the last line of append is not correct  it should be `hideBtnScript.Append("</script>");`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Thanks, I fixed the script tag. Regarding the script location, yes you are propably right. It just seems weired that the attribute being set is "ignored". Either it is overwritten after being set or maybe the document ready makes a difference. I'm not 100% sure myself. It could be a completly different localized issue off course all together.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Seems in this SO post the OP solved a similar issue with document ready too (See OP's own answer for details): [RegisterClientScriptBlock confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684596/registerclientscriptblock-confusion) then again, this might be a different case.

Comment: he is using there `RegisterClientScriptBlock` BUT the op uses `RegisterStartupScript` they are quite different...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yeah the startup one should work by default. I only switched to scriptblock with document ready due to issue in this post. Sorry if I caused any confusion.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl : Yes, It shows the length 0 in alert box. Im giving up..nothing seems to work in this.. may be i should change methods rendering textbox n all..anyways I am thankful to all of you especially royi, Francois. Thank you..

Comment: @RoyiNamir : I just quit jQuery and ClientScript. I just disabled  textbox on pageload and Enabled it on Button click(where i had registerstartupscript).. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
  $("#txtname").prop('readonly', true); //lowercase
```

prop is a better choice. same goes for `checked="checked"`

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() only retrieves attributes.

it is all about **HTML attributes vs DOM properties.**

Comment: @codebrain this code should work. please open firebug and search for erros.

Answer (score 1):

Change `ReadOnly` to `readonly`

```
$("#txtname").attr('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $("#txtname").prop('readonly', true);
```

**updated**

```
$("#<%= txtname.ClientID %>").prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: function hidebtn() {
        alert("hi");
        $('#diviv').css({
            "display": "block"
        });  
        $('#txtname').prop('readonly',true);
        } I tried this, i got the alert but still iam able to edit the text in text box ..

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("#<%= txtname.ClientID %>")
```

as follow

```
$("#<%= txtname.ClientID %>").attr('ReadOnly', true);
```

all together

```
function hidebtn() {        
$('#diviv').css({
    "display": "block"
});

$("#<%= txtname.ClientID %>").attr('ReadOnly', true);
}
```

Or Set the controls property `ReadOnly` to `False`

Answer (score 0):

You should use this for change input to readonly

```
$("#txtname").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to some Rendering Issues, Nothing seems to work properly. So i just replaced jQuery and Client script with Enabling/Disabling the Textbox.

Thanks